# Generate Java Classes from .xsd schema in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to generate JavaClasses for an existing .xsd file. From the command line I could already manage to do so.

To acheive the same in eclipse I tried to rightclick on the .xsd > Generate > JAXB Classes... but in the next dialogue I get the Error:

> " The classpath for this project does not appear to contain the
>   necessary libraries to proceed with class generation."

I found many answsers refering to using the correct JDK, but I have already set jdk1.8.0 as a preference. (I use Eclipse Kepler)

I hope I provided all neccessary information and that anyone can help me fix this issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you added all system library along with JDK or JRE added in eclipse environment???

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I chack that? There is the "JRE System Library" and a "Maven Dependencies" Entry in the Java BuildPath, and they both contain several jars e.g. javax.persistence...jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by adding jaxb jar files to my project's classpath.  I included: jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar, jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar, and jaxb-xjc-2.3.0.jar.  The impl jar was only added when I started using a bindings file which required me to enable vendor extensions.  Otherwise the core and xjc jars were all I needed.  I included links to where I got my jars in case you do not already have them

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.3.0

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0

Comment: Thank you, that did the job for me!